# Trouble Accessing Azure Windows VM File Share

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, azure, azure-activedirectory, identity-management

I'm encountering an issue with my Azure setup, and I could use some assistance. I have two Windows VMs, named `vm1` and `vm2`, both running Windows Server 2022. They are part of the same virtual network (VNet), and I've configured AD login via the Azure Active Directory (AAD) extension on both VMs as well.

##### Here's the problem:

When I RDP into `vm1` using my AD account, everything works smoothly. However, when I attempt to access a file share on `vm2` using the RUN dialogue (`\vm2\e$\test`), I consistently receive an `access denied` error, despite both VMs allowing login for the same user.

As a temporary workaround, I've discovered that logging into `vm2` via RDP first resolves the issue. After doing this, I can successfully access `\vm2\e$\test` from `vm1` without any problems.

I've tried different things but nothing helped, I would appreciate any insights or guidance to help me resolve this issue.